# Determining the number of vertices of a graph given the edges?

Tags: graph-theory

Here is the problem that I am working on right now.

How many vertices will the following graph have if it contains:

21 edges, three vertices of degree 4, and the other vertices of degree 4

Here was what I tried doing.

You know that

$$2\lvert E\rvert=\sum_{v \in V}deg(v) $$

Let $x$ denote the number of other vertices.

So $$2(21)=3(4)+4x$$

but when I try solving this equation for $x$ I end up getting

$x=7.5$

Which isn't possible because you can't have one half of an edge.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your solution is alright. There will not exist such a graph. Check the problem again.

Comment: @Miz It was a practice problem for final exam prep. I guess it must've been a typo.

Comment: Seems so. There is probably an errorr in the statement "three vertices of degree 4, and the other vertices of degree 4 "

Comment: Another possibility is that you are supposed to conclude that there must be some vertices that don't have degree 4. One possible answer might be that  there are 9 degree 4 vertices, 1 degree 5 vertex and 1 degree 1 vertex. Definitely check the problem and see if anything was left out.